# Using Joda time to get current wall time for a given Time Zone

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

The requirement is to simply to get the current wall time (**including the correct DST adjustment**) for a given Time Zone.

There seems to be a few questions in SO hovering around this, but I can't seem to find a straight answer (in SO, Joda doco or googling) with a low friction way of getting the wall time. It seems like with the given inputs (current UTC time and desired TZ) I should be able to chain a couple methods from the Joda Time library to achieve what I want but there seems to be a desire in said examples to evaluate + handle offsets / transitions in application code - I want to avoid this if possible and just use Jodas best effort based on its set of static TZ rules available.

For the purposes of this question, lets assume that I wont be using any other third party services (network based or other binaries), just what is available from the JDK and JodaTime library.

Any pointers appreciated.

**Update:**
This was actually a gaffe on my behalf. I had a *calculated* UTC offset based on the requests longitude, while this works obviously you still need regional information to get the correct DST adjustment..

```
double aucklandLatitude = 174.730423;
int utcOffset = (int) Math.round((aucklandLatitude * DateTimeConstants.HOURS_PER_DAY) / 360);
System.out.println("Offset: " + utcOffset);

DateTimeZone calculatedDateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(utcOffset);
System.out.println("Calculated DTZ: " + calculatedDateTimeZone);
System.out.println("Calculated Date: " + new DateTime(calculatedDateTimeZone));
System.out.println();
DateTimeZone aucklandDateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Pacific/Auckland");
System.out.println("Auckland DTZ: " +  aucklandDateTimeZone);
System.out.println("Auckland Date: " + new DateTime(aucklandDateTimeZone));
```

prints

```
Offset: 12
Calculated DTZ: +12:00
Calculated Date: 2012-02-08T11:20:04.741+12:00

Auckland DTZ: Pacific/Auckland
Auckland Date: 2012-02-08T12:20:04.803+13:00
```

So here in sunny [Auckland, NZ](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=22) we are +12 but +13 in the DST period.

My bad. Thanks for the answers nonetheless, made me see my mistake.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you looked at the `DateTime` constructor:

```
DateTime(DateTimeZone zone)
```

This constructs a DateTime representing the current time in the specified timezone.

Comment: I'd prefer `DateTime.now(DateTimeZone zone)` as I find it more obvious.

Comment: By the way, to adjust time zone call `withZone( myTimeZone )`.

Answer (score 15):

How about:

```
DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
DateTime losAngelesDateTime = utc.toDateTime(tz);
```

Comment: Correct, but two issues. (A) no need for passing millis of current time, Joda-Time does that for you internally. That argument is for conversions when your code has been handed a milliseconds count. (B) 'local' is a poor choice of var name because of confusion with LocalDate which means no time zone.

Comment: `.forId` should be `.forID`, by the way.

Answer (score 10):

### Cleanest Method

I find the following to be the cleanest method.

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

This gets you the current time in **UTC** but this value can be converted to another `DateTimeZone` or you can replace `DateTimeZone.UTC` with a different `DateTimeZone`.

#### Using the System TimeZone

If you want to set it to the system timezone, you can use this:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.getDefault() );
```