# Dynamic Date and Time for a specific country

Tags: java, date, timezone, locale, gregorian-calendar

I need a method for getting dynamic date and time to display it on the `JFrame` through a label in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format in Java Netbeans. I used one but that was 2 hours ahead of my country time. Following is the method I used:

```
public void currentDate(){
    Thread clock  = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        for(;;){
            //empty for will run forever
            //System.out.print("p");
            Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

            lab_date.setText(day+"/"+(((month+1)<10)?"0"+(month+1):(month+1))+"/"+year+"  "
                    + hour+":"+minute+":"+second
                    );

                try {
                    sleep(1000);//1000 miliseconds it will sleep which means one second sleep
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
        }
    }
    };
    clock.start();
}
```

Comment: Try Joda time API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331063/how-to-get-properly-current-date-and-time-in-joda-time

Comment: please be patient as i am new to this site and also use simple code as much as possible thanks in advance

Comment: *"Dynamic Date and Time for a specific country"*  My country (Australia) spans 2-3 time zones, North America is about the same (for the mainland below Canada part) and Russia crosses about 10.  For many countries there is no 'one specific time' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample illustration to get Date / time for Pakistan country:

```
    // create a simple date format instance
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss");
    // get the time zone of Paskistan country
    TimeZone pakistan = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Karachi");
    // set the time zone to the date format
    sdf.setTimeZone(pakistan);
    // print the date to the console
    System.err.println(sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Locale is not related to time zone.  One affects formatting.  The other affects the actual value.

Comment: Your are right but the SimpleDateFormat do the job for us i think ?

Comment: Thanks for this kindness but sir its giving an error in this line lab_date.setText(sdf.format(new Date())) ;
no suitable constructor for Date()... something like this.
i copied only the method and over-pasted on the old one and the upper three variables i declared as global in my JFrame class named as HomeFrame

Comment: in your import wich Date is used ? copy paste the Date import please

Comment: now fine but sir how to do it for pakistan, as the time is running 2 hours ahead of my country

Comment: In theory, nothing more that call ´Locale.getDefault()´, it will give you the Locale of your Operating System, and the Locale does retrieve the good TomeZone for You ! But Pakistan don't have the appropriate Locale default, define in Locale, so it seam appear another question no ? We need to work as required by site i think

Comment: it is 2:17 PM this time on my OS while my Loccale.getDefault(); gives me 04:17... 
this is the problem

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

You are using old classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar) that are now supplanted in Java 8 and later by the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

[Time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is an adjustment into someone's [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) while following a set of rules for offset-from-[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), and other anomalies. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never the 3-4 letter codes such as "EST" or "IST".

[Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) determines the formatting of a String representation of a date-time value according to cultural norms of style and a particular human language (French, German, whatever). I suggest you let java.time do the work of formatting in a localized manner rather than you controlling the formatting. The enum [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to choose shorter or longer formats.

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC. We then adjust into a time zone. Lastly create a string based on a particular Locale's formatting.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale );
String output = zdt.format( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "instant: " + instant );
System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run.

```
instant: 2015-09-26T04:59:34.651Z
zdt: 2015-09-26T00:59:34.651-04:00[America/Montreal]
output: samedi 26 septembre 2015 0 h 59 EDT
```

Comment: Sir where and how to use this code , i need just a method which i call and my jLable "lab_date" is set to the dynamic time. I want to set it to Pakistan Time

Comment: @JalalAhmad What is "dynamic time"? I suspect you mean the current moment. I showed how to do that in my Answer. `Instant.now` gives you the current moment in UTC. To adjust into a locality, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Follow link I gave for proper time zones to find a desired zone such as [`Asia/Karachi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Karachi), calling `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant` as seen above. Specify a Locale appropriate to the human language and cultural norms for your users. To automatically update, learn about Swing Timer or `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, to get date and day of your region.

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
```

**Output:**

Tue May 15 00:36:48 PKT 2018