# How to link the systems date to app.?

Tags: java, time, calendar, timetable

I am trying to create an app that reminds us to do chores on the particular day. I wanna know how to link the date,day and time of the system to the app. For eg: If today is Tuesday, i want the app to automatically change the day from Tuesday to Wednesday tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of selections you could use.

```
import java.util.Date;
Date date=new Date();    

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
new GregorianCalendar().getTime();
```

I personally like the jodatime library. Example use found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331063/how-to-get-properly-current-date-and-time-in-joda-time)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way so that i can link google calendar to my app. For eg if today is Dec 25 then my app should automatically show it as holiday.

Comment: I'm unsure, never looked into it. Read the documentation for the three libraries and see.