# POJO to Entity mapping with ModelMapper

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jackson, azure-cosmosdb, modelmapper

My POJO has a variable annotated like this

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx")
@JsonDeserialize(using = ZonedDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private ZonedDateTime startTs;

//other private variables
```

My goal is to map this to an Entity for which I'm using ModelMapper and the sample code goes like this

```
public POJOEntity mapToPOJOEntity(POJO pojo) {
    return modelMapper.map(pojo, POJOEntity.class);
}
```

After mapping when I look at the `startTs` variable in debug mode it has the desired format but when I check in the db `startTs` is saving as a whole `ZonedDateTime` object rather than the desired format I specified in POJO. Did anyone face this issue if yes can someone please help?
Value saved in cosmosDB:
[image: Value in cosmosDB]

Expected output: `"startTs": "2023-01-12T08:58:32.452-06:00"`

PS: CosmosDB, spring-boot, Java8, ModelMapper version: 2.3.8

Comment: Filed has data type ‘ZonedDateTime’.‘ Not sure why do you expect to see ‘String’ there?

Comment: ‘ @JsonFormat’ should  take effect when you serialize your POJO to json and mapper just map one object to another

Comment: Since I'm using @JsonFormat after serializing and saving it to the db it should save in this format `"2023-01-12T08:58:32.452-06:00"` since that is the pattern I'm using but it is saving the whole object as shown in image.

Comment: not sure how cosmosDB serializes it but your question was about ModelMapper. To validate your annotations you can create test using Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize explicitly and check results

Comment: I did not find anything online to fix this. I went with converting ZonedDateTime to String and saving it to the CosmosDB.

Comment: In .net using `NodaTime` package, we are able to store datetime in desired format on Cosmos DB.

For Java the alternative of the `NodaTime` package is `Joda Time`
Here are some references.

[JodaTime](https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/rationale)

[Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/joda-time/)

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331063/how-to-get-properly-current-date-and-time-in-joda-time)